# Was GMail hacked?

Tags: phishing, gmail

I was logging in to my gmail and this phising alert screen showed. Is safe to continue? I know that is very rare that this shows when opening GMail, but I prefer to be safe.

It seems that this appeared in the screen that asks me to enter again the password

[image]

Comment: Could be a [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Doubtful Gmail itself has been hacked. If it was, you probably wouldn't see this.

Comment: Looks like you are accessing the site via HTTP which could allow an attacker able to modify your traffic to serve you a phishing page. Try adding the "https://" to the URL and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

Probably only false positive, it happened also before with gmail, facebook etc.

This was from 2010 (Opera - Facebook):

> We are aware of the false positive Fraud warning. Should be fixed
>   ASAP. For now use http://www.facebook.com and not
>   http://www.facebook.com/?ref=logo We are sorry for any inconvenience
>   this might have caused..

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe. Once I saw the same problem. URL is quite good. But check it through you browser debugger. It is possible that some plugins can be responsible for that warning. Check your browsers settings, hosts file.

Just for your information visit this [link](http://shamindraparui.blogspot.in/2016/04/digital-forensicsspyware.html).

Comment: Please include the critical information the OP might need from the link inside your answer, as this link _might and will break_.